# run function after the user has entered the 4 first digits in an input field

Tags: javascript, html, function, call

I have an input field for credit cards and I want to run a function after the user has entered the 4 first digits of the card number in order to indicate the card type.

I want the function to run only one time and then stop.

I tried with timer but I did not like the result because the form was reloading every few seconds. I also don't want to wait until the user stops typing the whole number.

Comment: Please can we see some code, sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check it with [**onkeyup**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup) event, like this:

```js
var testIt = function testIt(num) {

  if (num.length === 4) {
    alert("more than 4 characters have been entered");
  }
}
```

```html
Card number: <input type="number" onkeyup="testIt(this.value);" />
```

***It will only execute if you enter the fourth number.***